# Access of lock by a thread using subclasses on parent class static variable in java

Tags: java, multithreading

Can a thread having access to a sub class object take a lock on its  parent class static variable in a synchronized block, if some other thread, having access to some other sub class object which inherits the same parent, has already taken a lock on that static variable?

Comment: What makes you think sub classes and static variable gave different locking rules?

Comment: I was wondering if different sub classes have different copy of static variable of parent class.

Comment: Well, that would be your *real* question. Edit your question to include that.

Comment: Re, "...a lock on its parent class static variable...".  There is no mechanism in Java to lock a _variable_.  You can only lock _objects_.

Comment: "Can a thread ... take a lock ... if some other thread ... has already taken a lock on [the same object?]"  No.  The rule is very simple.  No two threads will ever be allowed to hold locks on the same object at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is ["*mu*"](http://c2.com/cgi-bin/wiki?MuAnswer).

Locks are not taken by classes but by threads, so there is no valid answer to your question.

(Also, there are inner classes, there are subclasses, but there is no such thing as a *child* class, I'm afraid)

---

Looking at your edited question: 
Only one thread can hold a synchronized lock at a time. The thread that holds it can take the lock as many times as it likes: it will not block when it enters another synchronized block that synchronizes on the same object.

The relation between classes doesn't come into play when looking at locks.
So if the variable is static, and you synchronize on it from one thread, then another thread cannot synchronize on it at the same time - it has to wait for the first synchronized block to be finished. That is regardless of what classes or objects the thread has access to.

Comment: I edited the question, can you answer now?

Comment: Thanks...Means all different sub classes will share the static variable of parent class. Say, Subclass A and Subclass B will not have different parent's static variable for their instances?

Answer (score 3):

> Can a child class object take a lock on parent class static variable

Threads acquire a lock on the *instance* (Object). No, if one thread acquires a lock, then another thread will have to wait until the first thread releases the lock. Note that classes don't acquire locks, threads do.